# PhpStorm + Live Edit, не работает дебаггинг подключёенного css-файла

Tags: google-chrome, отладка, phpstorm

Добрый день. Подключил к IDE PhpStorm Live Edit, поставил расширение на Chrome. В проекте выбираю html файл, в контекстном меню - "Debug index.html" - всё работает, всё вроде хорошо. Но стили у меня хранятся в подключённом файле styles.css, и те изменения, которые я туда вношу не отображаются. Если я навожу в проекте на styles.css - в контексном меню для css-файлов нет дебагинга, как для html-файлов. Но в сети вижу видео - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0Db0TTZJa8, в нём парень правит css файл и на странице сразу видны изменения. Каким образом можно настроить дебаггинг подключённого css-файла?

Есть конечно извращённый метод - копировать из css файла все стили и запихивать в шапку, тогда всё работает, но очень хотелось бы так не извращаться.

Comment: Такой же вопрос.
> Каким образом можно настроить дебаггинг подключённого css-файла?

Comment: Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у Вас есть другие вопросы, Вы можете задать их нажав кнопку "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Дополнительно Вы можете [добавить вознаграждение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), чтобы привлечь к вопросу больше внимания, когда Ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет достаточного уровня.